# What interval is a Taylor polynomial of order n accurate at estimating a function?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

For the function $f(x)$ a Maclaurin polynomial of order $n$ around $0$ will approximate $f(0)$ very accurately, so that for many practical applications it is identical to its approximation. What is the interval within which a Taylor polynomial of order $n$ is reasonably accurate (within $\pm 0.01$) to $f(x)$?

Comment: Why not jus use the error formula for Taylor polynomials, you can find it in wikipedia or many other places?

Comment: Your question is under-specified. An answer to this question will depend on what "reasonably accurate" means, and it will also depend on $f$ and $a$.

Comment: Absolute error is usually not what people care about in practical application, usually people care about relative error instead...but either way, the error formula will do the job if you have a specific tolerance in mind. At least if you can get the required derivative estimate.